# Import jQuery in TypeScript 1.6.2 in Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, typescript1.6

I'm working on a crawler using Node.js. I use jQuery for parsing pages built using
`jsdom`.

I found a [jquery.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) through `tsd`, which ends like this:

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

This definition seems to be usable only on client side where jQuery is loaded
globally or where a global window variable is available...

As explained [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/dist/jquery.js#L18-L24),
when imported (using `require`) in an environment where `window.document` is not
available (like Node.js), jQuery export a factory of itself which has to be
initalized with a window object:

```
// JavaScript (ES5)
var jquery = require("jquery");
// ...
var $ = jquery(window);
```

But with TypeScript, since the definition doesn't contain this factory. It
doesn't work:

```
// TypeScript
import jquery from "jquery"; // Module '"jquery"' has no default export
import {jquery} from "jquery" // Module '"jquery"' has no exported member 'jquery'
import {jQuery} from "jquery" // Module '"jquery"' has no exported member 'jQuery'
import {$} from "jquery" // Module '"jquery"' has no exported member '$'
import * as jquery from "jquery"; // Doesn't complain here, but `jquery` variable is not usable
```

I tried to write a definition of this factory, but it seems to not be as simple
as I tought:

```
interface JQueryFactory {
    (window: any): JQueryStatic;
}

declare module "jquery" {
    export default JQueryFactory;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

And use it:

```
// TypeScript
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

import jquery from "jquery";
// ...
var $ = jquery(window); // error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jquery'
```

But now I have this strange error ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer to my question:

I was very close, now, my `jquery.d.ts` ends like this:

```
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
declare function jQueryFactory (window: any): JQueryStatic;
declare module "jquery" {
    export default jQueryFactory;
}
```

I didn't succeed to achieve this without declare the `jQueryFactory` function.

As a small example, it can now basically be used like this :

```
import {env}  from "jsdom";
import jquery from "jquery";

interface StuffInterface
{
    title: string;
    text: string;
}

function parse (url: string): Promise<StuffInterface>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        env(url, (e, window) => {
            if (e) {
                reject(e);
                return;
            }

            var $ = jquery(window);
            var stuff = {
                title: $('#stuff h1').text(),
                text: $('#stuff .content').text()
            };

            resolve(stuff);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting your own answer @Ascarius, could you please provide more detail on how you fixed it? I'm facing the same problems. Thanks!

Comment: @asheinfeld I added a basic example.

Comment: great, thanks @Ascarius! Maybe you should do a PR for jquery.d.ts so that everyone enjoys this, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By `TypeScript 1.8.9` without polluting `jquery.d.ts`

main.ts

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$' // Trick here!!!
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_' // Trick here!!!
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery.min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore.min'
    }
});

require(['foobar'], function (foobar) {
    foobar.runMe();
});
```

foobar.ts

```js
import 'jquery';
import 'underscore';

export function runMe() {
    console.log($); // this print jquery object
    console.log(_); // this print underscore object
}
```

Comment: Off topic : The problem here concerns environments where `window` is not available, i such case, jquery export a factory, which is not corresponding with `jquery.d.ts`